# jQuery: put a default value in all empty textboxes

Tags: jquery

<sub>*Textbox refers to `<input type="text">` in this question.*</sub>

For each textbox with a given class i would like to check if the value equals `''`, and if it does I want to make the value `'0'`. I would like to do this as soon as the page is loaded.

This is the closest I've got now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.myclass').val() == '') $('.myclass').val('0');
})
```

The problem here is that this code will give all my textboxes (with `class="myclass"`) the value `'0'` as soon as one of them is empty. I know this is the expected behaviour given the code I use now, but I'm pretty new to jQuery and I haven't really got the hang of the selectors yet. How would I solve this? Do I need to create a separate function to do the check on one element and then call that for each of the elements that apply to the selector? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: `textarea` or `<input type="checkbox" />`? You say different things at different points in the question...

Comment: sorry, i meant textbox. corrected it

Comment: `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`?

Comment: i don't need to check if it's a textbox. there arn't any elements other than <input type="text"> with class="myclass". I should have made my question more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4, [a function can be passed](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) to *val()* that will be executed on all elements in the collection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myclass').val(function (index, value) {
    // If the element has a value, return it, else return "0"
    return value || "0";
  });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EPyZx/)

For versions older than jQuery 1.4, you need to use [*.each()*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on the collection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myclass').each(function() {
        this.value = this.value || "0";
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EPyZx/2/)

Comment: this just outputs "function (index, value) { return value || "0"; }" as if it where a string...

Comment: @user296430: Are you using an older version of jQuery?  Like I said in the answer, this applies to 1.4 and later.  For older versions of jQuery you have to use [ *.each()* ](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the elements in the collection.

Comment: oh sorry, i'm indeed using 1.3 :)

Comment: @user296430: no worries, I updated my answer with an alternative example :-)

Comment: ok, thanks, didn't know that the ||-operator could be applied to strings also. That's pretty neat. I'll accept this as best answer

Answer (score 3):

This might be the simplest answer:

```
$("input.myclass[value=]").val("0");
```

Only elements with no value get selected. This works because the value attribute reflects the text the user put in.

Comment: +1 from me for the blindingly obvious solution that the rest of us missed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myclass[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
      if($(this).val()=='')
          $(this).val('0');
    });
})
```

Comment: This works only for the first element in the selection. You need to use each.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('input:checkbox').each( function() {
    // check the val
    if( $(this).val()=='')
      // do something
  });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Guess you made a typo: this.val() should be $(this).val()